# How to create groups in ReportViewer?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, reportviewer

I have this result on my query.

[image]

This result is from my sales table, each sale has an `ID`, and I have a table of products sold, each product sold has the sale `ID` as a foreign key, which represents the `ID_NF` in the result below:

[image]

How do I create a table or matrix in which each product that has the `ID_NF` equal to the sales `ID` is within its group.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join result which is from *sales* table with table of *products*. Condition for join will be `ID = ID_NF`. Sort it by sales, and then by products, for the sake of the result on report.

`SELECT * FROM dbo.Sales s
    INNER JOIN dbo.Products p ON s.ID = p.ID_NF
ORDER BY
    s.ID,
    p.ID_Produto`

This select is just representing what you should do, write it so it suits your needs.

In your report (.rdl, or .rdlc file), create a table which will provide data about sales.

[image]

Set value of any column, for instance for the first column.

[image]

Group rows by sales *id*. You can do it by these steps:

1. right click on the row
2. from the menu select *Row Group*
3. select *Group Properties*
4. in newly opened window choose tab/card *General*
5. go to section *Group expressions*
6. click the *Add* button
7. in the newly added dropdown list choose *id* of the sale

[image]

One of the columns will be about products. Insert new table in the cell that is intersection of row that represents sale and column that represents products. In the newly added table add needed columns.

In this example new table of three columns is added in column *Products*.

[image]

Add values for the rest of the columns.

For these results

[image]

Report should look like this

[image]